# How to filter string with condition using python

Tags: python, string

I have string like this

```
s ='Jacky Chan || He is a CEO ||Managing Director and General Partner, B Robotics || San Francisco Bay Area'
```

How can I filter out "He is a CEO" part based on keyword "CEO" within the string to look like this using python?

```
output:
'Jacky Chan||Managing Director and General Partner, B Robotics || San Francisco Bay Area'
```

Comment: Since each part is separated by `||`, you can call `s.split('||')` and that will return a list of the separate parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we split the string using the delimiter `||`, we can inspect each split and only include it in our new string if it *does not* contain the string `'CEO'`.

```
'||'.join(substr for substr in s.split('||') if 'CEO' not in substr)
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are using `"||"` as a delimiter between parts of your string, so split your string by that delimiter:

```
parts = s.split("||")
```

Then you say `"CEO"` is a keyword for filtering out a part, so get every part that doesn't have `"CEO"` in it:

```
filtered = [part for part in parts if "CEO" not in part]
```

Finally, put it back together:

```
output = "||".join(filtered)
```

Now you get

```
>>> print output
Jacky Chan ||Managing Director and General Partner, B Robotics || San Francisco Bay Area
```

I assume the output you posted was incorrectly spaced. If not, well, there's something else to be done here. You'll have to clarify for me.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with the other answers, but for the sake of completeness, here's how you could do it with regular expressions. Assumes that `|` is *only* used for delimiting.

```
import re
s ='Jacky Chan || He is a CEO || Managing Director and General Partner, B Robotics || San Francisco Bay Area'
print(re.sub(r'\|\|[^|]*CEO[^|]*\|\|', '||', s))
```

You can learn all about regular expressions, including the Python-specific bits, in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
s ='Jacky Chan || He is a CEO ||Managing Director and General Partner, B Robotics || San Francisco Bay Area'
y = "||".join([a for a in s.split("||") if not 'CEO' in a])
print(y)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could split the string on the `||` and then rejoin it excluding that segment. So:

```
s ='Jacky Chan || He is a CEO ||Managing Director and General Partner, B Robotics || San Francisco Bay Area'

s = s.split('||')

s = '||'.join(x for x in s if 'CEO' not in x)
```

And put it all together for a comprehension:

```
'||'.join(x for x in s.split('||') if 'CEO' not in x)
```

Here's also a regex version:

```
re.sub(r'\|\|[A-z\s]*[CEO]+[A-z\s]*\|\|', "||", s)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can look for `CEO` and strip away everything between the `||` separators that contains it, e.g.:

```
s ='Jacky Chan || He is a CEO ||Managing Director and General Partner, B Robotics || ' \
   'San Francisco Bay Area'

index = s.find("CEO")  # or any other string
if index != -1:  # string found
    replaced = s[:s.rfind("||", 0, index)] + s[s.find("||", index):]
    print(replaced)

# Jacky Chan ||Managing Director and General Partner, B Robotics || San Francisco Bay Area
```